# How to stop a while loop in C

Tags: c

In this code, the computer asks the user what he wants to purchase between 1-7 options. And if the user presses the wrong option up to 3 times -> computer will print this message: "Do you want to leave or make a purchase? Press y(for leave) or n(for stay)". I know another way how to do this, but how can I stop the while loop and print a message?

!!!This is incorrect code(has mistakes), used for example!!!

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int DisplayMenu();
double OrderPrice(int itemNumber);

int main 
{
   char process = 'y';
   int mainOption;
   while (process == 'y' || process == 'Y')
   {
      optionMain = DisplayMenu();
      printf("\nYour choice was %d", optionMain);
   };
  return 0;
}

int DisplayMenu()
{
   int option, optionCount;
   printf("1 - ..., 2 - ..., 3 - ..., 4 - ..., 5 - ..., 6 - ..., 7 - ...");
   scanf("%d", &option);

   while (option > 7 || option < 1) {
        printf("Make your chose between 1-7:");
        scanf(" %d", &option);

        optionCount++;
        if (optionCount == 2) {
            printf("Do you want to leave or make a purchase? Press y(for leave) or n(for stay)");
        }
    };


   return option;

   return 0;
}

double OrderPrice(int itemNumber)
{
    double price;
    switch (itemNumber) {
        case 1 :
            printf("\nSelection 1.");
            price = 1.1;
            break;
        case 2 :
            printf("\nSelection 2.");
            price = 2.2;
            break;
        case 3 :
            printf("\nSelection 3.");
            price = 3.3;
            break;
        case 4 :
            printf("\nSelection 4.");
            price = 4.4;
            break;
        case 5 :
            printf("\nSelection 5.");
            price = 5.5;
            break;
        case 6 :
            printf("\nSelection 6");
            price = 6.6;
            break;
        case 7 :
            printf("\nSelection 7.");
            price = 7.7;
            break;
//        default:
//            printf("Incorrect selection");
//            price = 0.00;
    }
    return price;
}
```

Comment: You need to get input at that point, test it, and if it's a stop request, `break`.

Comment: thank you! forgot about break ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️

Comment: Note that the semicolon at the end of `while (process == 'y' || process == 'Y') { … };` marks the end of an empty statement, not the end of the `while` loop (the `}` marks the end of the `while` loop).  In general, you don't want semicolons after `}` except after initializers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah I know, thank you. It's hard to control the semicolon when u did another language and never paid attention to it!

Answer (score 3):

was solved by @tadman: You need to get input at that point, test it, and if it's a stop request, break

```c
optionCount++;
if (optionCount == 2) {
  break;
}
```